# Java program which accepts a list of existing text files from command line arguments

Tags: java

> Question: write a Java program which accepts s list of existing text files from command line args and concatenates the contents of all files in "Master.txt".

My code gives an error while testing 4 `endsWith(".txt")`. Please let me know how to correct it.

```
import java.io.*;
class FileConcat
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  FileOutputStream fout;
  FileInputStream fin,fin1;
  File f;
  int b; 
  try
  {
   //open Master file
   try
   {
    fout=new FileOutputStream("Master.txt"); 
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
   }
   //traverse all args, check if valid text file, if yes, concatinate
   for(int j=0;j<args.length;j++)
   {
    f=new File(args[j]);
    if(f.isFile()==true)
    {
     if((args[j].endsWith(".txt"))==true)
     {
      try
      {
       fin=new FileInputStream(args[j]);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
       System.out.print("Error Opening "+args[j]);
      }
      while((b=fin.read())!=-1)
      {
       char ch=(char) b;
       fout.write(ch);
      }
     }
    fin.close();
    }
   }
   fout.close();
   fin1=new FileInputStream("Master.txt"); 
   while((b=fin1.read())!=-1)
   {
    char ch=(char) b;
    System.out.print(ch);
   }
   fin1.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
 }
}
```

The output:

```
C:\j2sdk1.4.1_01\bin>javac FileConcat.java
FileConcat.java:38: variable fin might not have been initialized
                                                while((b=fin.read())!=-1)
                                                         ^
FileConcat.java:41: variable fout might not have been initialized
                                                        fout.write(ch);
                                                        ^
FileConcat.java:44: variable fin might not have been initialized
                                fin.close();
                                ^
FileConcat.java:47: variable fout might not have been initialized
                        fout.close();
                        ^
4 errors
```

How do I check if `fin` is assigned a value or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter; <br>
import java.io.File;<br>
import java.io.FileWriter;<br>
import java.util.Scanner;<br>

public class ConcatFiles
{
    public static String masterFile;


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    MasterFile();
}

public static void MasterFile() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Enter Master File Name:");
    Scanner readMasterFileName = new Scanner(System.in);
    masterFile = readMasterFileName.next();
    if (new File(masterFile).exists() && masterFile.contains(".txt"))
    readFileName();
    else
    {
        if (masterFile.contains(".txt"))
        {
            new File(masterFile).createNewFile();
            System.out.println("Master File Created");
            readFileName();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid File or Input");
            MasterFile();
        }
    }
}
public static void readFileName() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Enter File Names:");
    Scanner readOtherFiles = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cmd = readOtherFiles.next();

    if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"))
        System.exit(0);
    else
        if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("New"))
            MasterFile();
        else
            if (cmd.contains(".txt") && new File(cmd).exists())
            concatFile(cmd);
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input or File");
                readFileName();
            }
}
public static void concatFile(String otherFiles)throws Exception
{
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(masterFile, true));
    File readFiles = new File(otherFiles);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(readFiles);
    while(reader.hasNext())
    {
        out.write(reader.nextLine()+"\n");
    }
    out.close();
    readFileName();
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you don't assign anything at all to fin and fout when you declare them, you only assign to them in a try{} block, and the code that subsequently uses them is outside the try{} block; so if an exception is thrown inside the try{} block, the program will continue regardless and attempt to use the uninitialised values.

Your options are:

- Move the code trying to use these variables inside the try{} block where they are initialised
- Assign `null` to these variables when declaring them, and place the code that tries to use them in an `if (variable != null) {}` block.
- Make the catch() clauses perform some action that guarantees the code that would otherwise try to use uninitialised variables does not execute, e.g. exit the program
- Just get rid of the try.. catch clauses and declare the whole method as throwing those exceptions

Comment: Unrelated to the answer, but I love the Cat Stevens reference in your name (or, alternatively, the PS238 reference)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to say:

```
if (b == true)
```

When `b` is some `boolean`. This is equivalent to:

```
if (b)
```

This doesn't answer your question (as others already have) but might be useful for you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with the following section (and other similar ones):

```
try
{
  fin=new FileInputStream(args[j]);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.print("Error Opening "+args[j]);
}
```

If an exception is thrown, then `fin` will not have been initialised with a value. However, if an exception is thrown, then arguably your program cannot continue. Therefore I think you should remove the try/catch and just declare that your `main` method `throws IOException`.

Answer (score 0):

If `fout = new FileOutputStream("Master.txt");` throws an exception then `fout` is undefined but you are still attempting to write to the file.

Similarly if `fin = new FileInputStream(args[j]);` throws an exception then `fin` is undefined but you still attempt to read from the file.

You could enclose the whole loop in the `try` block, or just declare `main` to throw `IOException`.

I also recommend moving the calls to `close()` into `finally` blocks and removing the redundant `"==true" from some of the tests.`

```
import java.io.*;
public class FileConcat
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    FileOutputStream fout;
    FileInputStream fin,fin1;
    File f;
    int b; 

    //open Master file
    try
    {
      fout=new FileOutputStream("Master.txt"); 
      try
      {
        //traverse all args, check if valid text file, if yes, concatinate
        for(int j=0;j<args.length;j++)
        {
          f=new File(args[j]);
          if(f.isFile())
          {
            if(args[j].endsWith(".txt"))
            {
              try
              {
                fin=new FileInputStream(args[j]);
                try
                {
                  while((b=fin.read())!=-1)
                  {
                    char ch=(char) b;
                    fout.write(ch);
                  }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                  fin.close();
                }
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                System.err.println("Error opening "+args[j]+" for input");
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      finally
      {
        fout.close();
      }
      fin1=new FileInputStream("Master.txt"); 
      while((b=fin1.read())!=-1)
      {
        char ch=(char) b;
        System.out.print(ch);
      }
      fin1.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Error opening Master.txt for output");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question at its face value, you can check if fin is assigned a value using

```
if (null == fin)
```

The actual cause, though, is because you're continuing execution if an exception is thrown.

```
 try
  {
   fin=new FileInputStream(args[j]);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.print("Error Opening "+args[j]);
  }
```

The above block doesn't set `fin` if an Exception is thrown, yet you access `fin` in the very next line.  This also applies to `fout` and `fin1`.

You can nest other code in a try block; the is actually recommended if you're using resources that may throw exceptions when access them.

Comment: That will only work if fin and fout are also initialised to null.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the variables at the beginning of your method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    FileInputStream fin = null;
    FileInputStream fin1 = null;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the variables thus:

```
FileOutputStream fout = null;
FileInputStream fin = null, fin1 = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

you add return statement in catch block...rest is fine....
eg :

try{

}
catch(ExcepttionName exObject)
{
    statements;
    return;

}

you have to add return in every catch() block.